# How to call a RESTful web service in the async way?

Tags: java, rest

I am wondering how to call a RESTful web service ***asynchronously***? Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by an asynchronous call? Do you want the client to make the request asynchronously? Do you want the server to respond immediately (e.g. for a long-running job) and invoke some sort of callback when it's finished? Please clarify your question.

Comment: In Java, you can use the CompletealeFuture of java 8, also Guava, Spring provided alternative ways that run on older JDK versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possible solutions, depending if you want push or pull.

1) The caller can add a callback URL in the request HTTP header. This URL will be called by the service when the process is finished.

2) The service can add a process URL in the answer HTTP header. the caller can thus get information about the advance of his request and get the result when it is done.

Comment: The callback URL depends on the service you are calling.

Answer (score 3):

Since REST is based on HTTP, which is a synchronous request/response protocol, your only alternative is to wrap it in an asynch call on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use client side code to async the sync call for the RestFul Web Service Call.